# octave - how to fopen from same directory as running program

Tags: octave, fopen

My file structure is

```
/home/me
  + octave
    - script.m
    + data
      - index.txt
```

In `script.m`:

```
fid = fopen("data/index.txt");
```

When I run script.m, it can't open/find the file.

When I do `pwd` in the script, it says `/home/me`

Is there a way to make the `fopen` always use the current directory (where script.m is running from) as the point of reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be because `script.m` is in your path and you are simply running it from `/home/me`? If you do `cd(octave)` before running `script.m`, can it then open/find the text file?